# Is it possible to get the slider to finish on the last image when on single loop and not able to again repeat to the first image

Tags: magento-1.9, slider, small-image

I need products small images slider stop after images over in the loop,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1.**

### In this first method the Nivo Slider starts and ends on the same image (slide 1).

[image]

The following javascipt code goes in your head tag, the slider has an ID of “slider“.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
        slideshowEnd: function(){$('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;} 
    });
});
```

---

**Method 2.**
In this second method the Nivo Slider only plays each image once.
Because of the way the slider works it always must end on slide 1. So what I did is force it to start on slide 2. So when it stops on slide 1 it has only played each image once. Put whatever image you want to be first in the slider as Slide 2. A little quirky, but hey..it works!

[image]

The following javascript code goes in your head tag, the slider has an ID of “slider“.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        startSlide:1, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
        slideshowEnd: function(){$('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;} 
    });
});
```

Comment: this is my script

Comment: https://github.com/lunchskate/Cloud-Zoom/blob/master/js/ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js

Comment: @JeevaRathinam give me some to give a look at your code

Comment: @ B Karthik Kumar : okay sure..

Comment: @JeevaRathinam The link you gave is of cloud zoom which you may have implemented on your site so just use above answer in your page where you have implemented the slider

Comment: @ B Karthik Kumar : okay..

Comment: @ B Karthik Kumar : could u pls help me where i can use this code

Comment: @ B Karthik Kumar: Am get confused, i gave what i used. Pls, let me know where i can insert the code what you mentioned above.

Comment: @ B Karthik Kumar : did u get any idea!!